# Java output of the main function

Tags: java

```
class Wg {
static int x = 0;
  int y;
  Wg() { y = x++; }
  public String toString() {
     return String.valueOf(y);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     String s = new Wg().toString();
     s += new Wg().toString();
     s += new Wg().toString();
     System.out.println(s);
} }
```

Why the output is 012. I am not sure when method WG will be invoked and the specific procedure

Comment: `x` is `static`, so each time you use `new Wg()` it increments `x` and then assigns the result to `y`.  The question is, what did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Creates an Object of Type Wg and invokes the toString Method
// x = static i.e. shared between all classes (here: x = 0)
// x++;
// s = String.valueOf(y) = "0"
String s = new Wg().toString();
// Creates an Object of Type Wg and invokes the toString Method
// x = static i.e. shared between all classes (here: x = 1)
// x++;
// s = "0"+String.valueOf(y) = "01"
s += new Wg().toString();
// Creates an Object of Type Wg and invokes the toString Method
// x = static i.e. shared between all classes (here: x = 2)
// x++;
// s = "01"+String.valueOf(y) = "012"
s += new Wg().toString();
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Every time I create an object of type wg and invoke toString Method, I will invoke wg method(y = x++) . Am I right? I just not sure about method wg in the wg class. wg(){y=x++} Is a method in class wg? And when this method will be called.... I am not sure what the wg(){y = x++} is and how to use that

Comment: Two seperate things happen when you call `s += new Wg().toString();` a) you create a new Object of Class Wg and call its Constructor `Wg(){y = x++}` b) you call the `.toString()` method on the newly created Object which returns `y` as a `String`. The `y = x++`could also be written like this: `x++;` & `y=x;`

Comment: So whenever I create a new object and I will call constructor automatically. Am i right?

Comment: Yes - in Java every class must have a constructor - if you don't create one yourself the compiler will create an empty one i.e. `ClassName(){}`

Answer (score 0):

`y = x++` equal

```
y = x;
x = x + 1;
```

so

```
 String s = new Wg().toString(); // "0"
 s += new Wg().toString(); // "0" + "1" == "01"
 s += new Wg().toString(); // "01" + "2" == "012"
```